# How to visualize new poses without simulation, using VTKRenderer

Tags: drake

```
builder = DiagramBuilder()
plant, scene_graph = AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph(builder, 0.0)

parser = Parser(plant)

renderer_name = "renderer"
renderer = MakeRenderEngineVtk(RenderEngineVtkParams())
scene_graph.AddRenderer(
    renderer_name, renderer)
...
for i, position in enumerate(positions):
    obj_joints[i].set_translation(plant_context, position)
diagram.Publish(diagram_context)
scene_graph.Publish(sg_context)
```

The above code does **not** update anything in the visualizer.

I must run:

```
simulator.AdvanceTo(100.0)
```

For anything to update visually.

How do I get the objects to move to their new poses without physics simulation?

Answer (score 2):

> ... does not update anything in the visualizer.

Is that `drake_visualizer`? It's worth noting that RenderEngines don't "visualize" geoemetry in that sense. They are part of the simulation of cameras and sensors in the actual simulation. What you *actually* want to do is attach an instance of `DrakeVisualizer` to your diagram as:

```py
DrakeVisualizer.AddToBuilder(builder, scene_graph)
```

(before you call builder.Build()).

That is the system responsible for populating `drake_visualizer` and is the system that would update `drake_visualizer` upon calling `Publish()` (and you'd only have to call `Publish` on the diagram, not `scene_graph` as well.

On the off chance, if you actually meant that you were attempting to produce rendered images inside the simulation from an `RgbdSensor`, the instructions would change.

Comment: Thanks. So even without Drake_Visualizer mentioned anywhere, just using the VTKEngine above we get a GUI window that shows the simulation. Are you saying if I add DrakeVisualizer it will replace that GUI window built with VTK Engine?

Comment: Did you call `ColorRenderCamera(..., show_window=True)` perhaps?  That would mean the window you're seeing is the preview image for a simulated camera.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't thought of the `show_window` parameter. Yes, you can use that parameter to show the last rendering. It's not interactive at all, but it does should you what the render engine has drawn over and over. 

The key is that you need to invoke the rendering every time you want the window to update. You either need to invoke the `QueryObject` query directly, or have it happen in the simulation by having something like `RgbdSensor`, regularly publish.

Comment: I want to clarify something. I already had: DrakeVisualizer.AddToBuilder(builder, scene_graph) in the code

Comment: Also the objects were created using: https://github.com/RussTedrake/manipulation/blob/bead198553d328bb2faeba5c22b493104dbf7657/manipulation/scenarios.py#L138

Comment: But basically, it does not work. The spheres created through add shape do not move

Comment: See [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69950297/plant-setpositions-does-not-update-visualization/69951636?noredirect=1#comment123656046_69951636). There was another "I set the pose, but things didn't move". In that case, the position wasn't being set as expected. Your original post doesn't provide sufficient information for me to tell if it applies to you, but you might check it out.