# plant.SetPositions does not update visualization

Tags: drake

My code (using Russ Tedrake's [manipulation module](https://github.com/RussTedrake/manipulation/blob/bead198553d328bb2faeba5c22b493104dbf7657/manipulation/scenarios.py#L138) to make shapes): https://gist.github.com/richardrl/b71a1b6ed9e30dfc9ac252cc99193634

The logic is in line 147 is completely ignored with respect to the visualizer. No matter what positions I set it, the visualization is the same.

Video here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/86werg0fxmbqebs/ball_horizontal_line.mp4?dl=0

The spheres pop out of the origin position (which they start off in from AddShape) and move outwards in a horizontal line, regardless of what configuration I set in line 147.

I am not positive whether this is a problem of, the visualization is disconnected from my plant, or something else. But what I do know is my code is setting the plant positions properly (console outputs):

```
ln145 before setting positions
[ 1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.]
ln156 after setting positions
[ 0.          0.          0.3         0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.6         0.          0.3         0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.3         0.          0.81961524  0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
ln163 after simulation
[ -2.48258262e-04   0.00000000e+00   2.99999898e-01   0.00000000e+00
   9.32950273e-04   0.00000000e+00   2.98500000e-01  -2.25902431e-01
   0.00000000e+00  -6.31659664e-01   0.00000000e+00  -1.30262016e+00
   0.00000000e+00   2.98500000e-01  -7.89982679e-01   0.00000000e+00
  -3.71132816e-01   0.00000000e+00   1.28836582e+00   0.00000000e+00
   2.98500000e-01]
```

EDIT: Here is a self-contained file that reproduces the error: https://gist.github.com/richardrl/6013299b63100c585851ed1803406cfa

Answer (score 2):

Here's what jumps out at me.

I believe you've got a fundamental problem. It looks like `AddShape` returns a *model instance* index and *not* a *body* index. But you're *using* it as a *body index* (more or less). This is causing you to slice into the generalized coordinates badly. So, when you *think* you're setting position, you're actually writing to the quaternion.

For example, in `STACKED_TOUCHING` touching configuration, sphere 1's *position* should be at [0, 0, 0.3]. And you see the *first three state* variables have been come [0, 0, 0.3], however those three values are the first three values of what *used* to be the unit quaternion [1, 0, 0, 0].

Generally, trying to directly interpret state can be a dangerous proposition. So, rather than trying to manipulate it, I'd recommend using the API where the actions you're taking are more easily interpretiable:

```py
for idx, sphere in enumerate(spheres):
    # Note: we're ignoring the model instance index entirely and
    # simply acquiring bodies based on their *globally* unique body names.
    sphere_name = f"sphere_{idx}"
    sphere_body = plant.GetBodyByName(sphere_name)
    plant.SetFreeBodyPose(plant_context, sphere_body,
                          RigidTransform(p=guesses, idx))
```

Some further random notes:

1. You've got *multiple* instances of `DiagramBuilder` and a diagram (lines 49-58 are no-ops because they are 100% replaced with the following definition.
2. The invocation of `scene_graph.Publish(sg_context)` on line 160 is redundant; the previous line where you publish the `diagram` *should* be sufficient.
3. Looking at your video, it seems like the spheres "organically" move out of collision (with each other and with the ground"). This makes some sense as they start in total collision (only arbitrarily rotated), so they have to move out of collision.
   If you look at your *final* position values. The 7th, 14th, and 21st values are all, basically, 0.3; the spheres have risen up to be radius height above the ground plane.

Comment: Just a comment about the first point - I actually modified scenarios.py so the body index should be correct: https://gist.github.com/richardrl/0aa119b6d1db88ef2f02dcc13f3ad4f6#file-scenarios-py-L186

Comment: Your third message solved the problem. I thought the q was structured like [pos, quat, pos, quat, ...] but it is actually [quat, pos, quat, pos...] I couldn't find this in the docs so I tried to reason about it implicitly and found the wrong mapping. It works now if I just modify the q indexing to match the position part correctly. The SetFreeBodyPose is also helpful, thanks

Comment: There is actually still one problem: the rendering in the DrakeVisualizer window does not update by this [line](https://gist.github.com/richardrl/b71a1b6ed9e30dfc9ac252cc99193634#file-sphere_stacking_3d-py-L158), after I set the positions. It only updates after I simulate. Any clue why?

Comment: (I applied fixes wrt to all the other comments already, by the way)

Comment: As for updating the visualizer -- Drake doesn't have a "push" architecture (where if you  make a change, the effect of it immediately propagates downwards). It has a pull architecture (when you evaluate a value, all upstream values get evaluated as necessary). So, to update the visualizer, you need to force the visualizer to send a message. Calling `diagram.Publish(context)` after updating plant state should always update the visualizer.

Comment: As far as the first point -- you were lucky that your model instance indices and body instance indices had a fixed offset. If any model had multiple bodies, or MbP changes its book keeping, the relationship between model instance and body would be arbitrarily different.

Comment: Hi Sean, I did call diagram.Publish though. In the line linked above, I check what the spheres look like right before simulation, and after publishing. The visualizer is still not updated?

Comment: Can you update the gist to be the actual updated code? The original gist was obviously flawed. If I can see the *new* code that is apparently not updating the visualizer, then I can take a better guess of what the problem is.

Comment: Sure, actually the current link is updated. The indexing change is on line 149, and other changes were also implemented

Comment: Ah...I see. And, presumably, nothing happens at line 155 where you call `Publish` on the `diagram`? Do you know about `lcm-spy`. It's a way for you to snoop on the messages being broadcast and you can confirm that a message is/isn't being sent. 

I presume the printout of the state now reflects much better configuration after writing to state. Looking at the gist, it's not clear to me why the visualizer wouldn't show updated position.

Comment: I have been developing for a while without the visualizer but just came back to try to fix it. yes, nothing happens at line 155.

Comment: lcm-spy outputs this: https://snipboard.io/1a74EC.jpg

Comment: I made this a self-contained script, only needs pydrake and numpy, can you try to reproduce the error? @Sean Curtis

Comment: https://gist.github.com/richardrl/6013299b63100c585851ed1803406cfa

Comment: Yeah...I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Have you had any luck? @Sean Curtis

Comment: Bad news -- I'm leaving TRI and a thousand things have ended up on my queue in preparation for that departure. I'm going to post a formal issue on Drake and reassign it to one of the team members.

Comment: https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/16183

Comment: I've posted an answer in the linked issue.